# c++ " was not declared in this scope error while using shared library generated by MySQL C API

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, libmysql

I generated a shared library which wraps MySQL C API functions. It has a sample.h and sample.cpp files like this

```
using namespace std;
class MysqlInstance
{
    protected:
    string user;
    string password;
    string socket;
    int port;

    public:
    MySqlInstance(string,string,string,port);
    int connectToDB();
 }
```

In sample.cpp

```
MySqlInstance::MySqlInstance(string user,string pass,string sock,int port)
{
 this->port=port;
 this->user=user;
 this->password=pass;
 this->socket=sock;
}
MySqlInstance::connectToDB()
{
 //code to load libmysqlclient.so from /usr/lib64 and use mysql_init and mysql_real_connect 
 // functions to connect and "cout" that connection is successful
}
```

Used:

- g++ -fPIC -c sample.cpp `mysql_config --cflags`
- g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,libsample.so -o libsample.so sample.o `mysql_config --libs`

Now libsample.so is generated and I moved it to /usr/lib
    Now I created a small cpp file which uses this shared library in the same directory.
   **usesample.cpp**

```
#include "sample.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 MysqlInstance* object=new MySQlInstance("root","toor","/lib/socket",3306);
}
```

Used:

- g++ -c usesample.cpp -lsample

It is giving me this error:

> error: âMysqlInstanceâ was not declared in this scope
>   error: object was not declared in this scope

Thanks

Comment: I don't know if it's a copy-paste error when posting your question, but you have two `port` member variables in your `MysqlInstance` class.

Comment: Yeah..thats a typo..the problem here is when I do the samething without MySQL C API and all I didnt get these types of errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few errors. One, is the constructor declaration

```
 MySqlInstance(string,string,string,port);
```

You probably mean

```
MySqlInstance(string,string,string,int);
```

Then, the definition, you have the type of `port` wrong:

```
MySqlInstance::MySqlInstance(string user,string pass,string sock,string port) { .... }
                                                              //   ^ should be int
```

Then, the class name

```
class MyqllInstance { .... };
```

should be

```
class MySqlInstance { .... };
```

Then, you are using `MySQlInstance` in `main` but your class is `MySqlInstance`.

Remember, C++ is **not case insensitive**.

Finally, do not put `using namespace std` in a header file. In fact, do not put it anywhere.

Comment: Sorry man but I typed it not copied and pasted mine is actually very big code I cant copy-paste it here. Dont mind the typos. But the problem is scope here not those silly ints ot strings..I removed using namespace std; from header file before It gave me a very big list of errors while creating libsample.so I was java programmer. realatively new to C++

Comment: @Sreekar I suggest you fix the cut and paste errors in your question. Otherwise it is impossible to help.

Comment: I corrected the error atlast.It was this VIM editor which made a single letter mistake in "MySqlInstance" and wasted 3 hours of my time. Thank you so much for your patience for reading my question and you help @juanchopanza

Answer (score 1):

Well, your class is named `MysqlInstance` but in your main() you refer to it as `MySQlInstance`, and in your cpp implementation you have `MySqlInstance`.

C++ is case-sensitive, so make sure you use the correct identifier everywhere.

Comment: The OP also referse to it at `MySqlInstance` as well. So in total three different capitalizations of one word. Including different capitalization in the header and source file for the actual library.